# Generating readable ids for dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

When working with dynamoDB and have a need to generate unique ids for customers, products or other things that users will come in contact with what is the correct way of doing it?

Sure UUIDs are great but its not something you can expect a customer to use and if I want to make my own on my server I have to make pretty awkward database calls to make sure I either use the next one in some sequence, save some weird extra field or make random stabs in the dark.

So how can I go about solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that UUIDs are still the way to go. Especially if you are looking to architect a scalable solution, then you can't rely on a single "point of failure" to generate some sort of sequential unique identifiers - anything like that will require synchronization and availability which are the enemy of performance in a distributed system.

However, if you'd like to generate some more human friendly identifiers, you have a couple of options:

1. you could start with UUIDs and fold those in half (take the first 8 bytes and xor with the last 8 bytes), then take the resulting 64-bit number and encode using a base 62 encoding (numbers from 0-9 plus upper and lower -case letters) to generate a 11 character string that is somewhat more human-friendly then a typical UUID; if you're ok with less entropy you could fold the UUID twice, obtaining a 32-bit number which you could encode into a 6 character base 62 representation, or an 7 character base 32 encoding which only uses numbers and upper case letters
2. the second approach you could take is to use a combination of mac address, time stamp and pseudo random number generator to generate your own ids, following a certain rule, similar to how UUIDs are generated but with less entropy, again, so that you may encode the IDs such that they are user friendly

You can prevent issues that could arise in the case where the same ID is accidentally generated in two different places, you can take advantage of [conditional writes to DynamoDB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.ConditionalWrites).

Comment: Thank you for your input, I'm sure we can find a solution doing something like this but I'm surprised how complex it is to solve this issue.

Comment: @Jeppz - yes, distributed computing is not trivial ;) by the way, I've added an edit to the answer to clarify that you can guard against potential duplicate IDs using conditional writes to DynamoDB

Answer (score 0):

you can use a counter in process cache (or cache - like memcache or redis) and use locks on this counter in order to get next value.

psaudo code:

```
function get_next_value():
    lock:
        counter+=1
        return counter
```